# Combination Fn::Join and Fn::Select in Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource, fn

How to combine Fn::Join and Fn::Select in Cloudformation template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", { "Fn::Select": ["0", { "Ref": "value" }] } ]] }
```